# Getting Phusion Passenger on nginx working in Fedora

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, fedora, passenger

I had nginx installed with yum. But I needed to install Phusion Passenger. I followed the guide on Passenger website and the command that installs nginx support actually compiled and installed another copy of nginx on my system with Passenger support. The default "service nginx start" for Fedora works with the initial yum installed nginx. If I need Passenger support I have to start nginx manually from /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx and it also uses a config file of its own. I would like to know if there was a cleaner or more proper way to get nginx and Phusion Passenger working on Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this on Ubuntu Server and I wound up uninstalled the nginx package and letting Passenger install nginx it for me.

From what I understand of nginx, it doesn't support modules like Apache does. So there's no way to install just a passenger module. It has to be baked into a special patched version of nginx.

Comment: Minor correction. Nginx does have "modules", but they must be included during compile time.